# Don't understand function to count digits in character array

Tags: c, arrays, character

I am having a lot of trouble understanding my professor's solution to a program that counts the number of digits in a character array.

```
int main(void)
{
    char* s[] = {"12, 34, 56, 78",
                 "82.16, 41.296",
                 "2, -3, 5, -7, 11, -13, 17, -19",
                 "9.00009, 90.0009, 900.009, 9000.09, 90000.9"};
    int i, rows = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      digitCounts( s[i] );
  }
}

void digitCounts(char* s) {
    int counts[10] = { 0 };
    int i = 0;

    while( s[i] != '\0' )
    {
        if('0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9')
            counts[ s[i] - '0' ]++;

        i++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        printf("%d, ", counts[i]);

    printf("%d\n\n", counts[i]);
}
```

Can someone please help me understand this section specifically:

```
while( s[i] != '\0' )
{
    if('0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9')
        counts[ s[i] - '0' ]++;

    i++;
}
```

I understand the while-loop conditional: if the element at s[i] is not equal to NUL, then proceed. But the if statement is confusing to me because are you comparing numerical values or string values? How can a string value be greater than or less than another? e.g. '1' <= '9'. Also, wouldn't the first element of s[] be '12'? Not '1'. In other words, it wouldn't be a single digit.

Please help I am really lost!

Comment: First of all - these are "character values", not "string values". Second: Have you heard of ASCII encoding?

Comment: He's simply checking if the ASCII value of the single character is between or including the ASCII values for the characters '0' and '9'. They are laid out contiguously in the ASCII table, which is why you can just check the upper and lower value.

Comment: `counts[ s[i] - '0' ]++;` is converting the character at `s[i]` to 0-based by subtracting the lowest character value in the range, `'0'`, and then counting the occurrences of that digit in the `counts[]` array element with that index.

Comment: There is nothing here that indicates that the execution character set is ASCII. Very often it is crucial to know the exact character set and encoding (and it is rare that it is ASCII). However, this is portable C code that simply relies on the requirement of C systems to have '0'-'9' as consecutive `char` values. The code that does this is `s[i] - '0'`, which is an expression that calculates the "distance" of a known 0-9 digit character from the '0' character. So, if you are looking at an ASCII table, you are making a mistake. It won't hurt this time, but….

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
if('0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9')
```

is comparing individual characters within a single string against the *character constants* `'0'` and `'9'` (ASCII values 48 and 57).

Remember that a *string* in C is a sequence of character values followed by a 0-valued terminator, and *string literals* are delimited by double quotes (`"`).  Strings (including string literals) are *stored* as arrays of `char`.  Each element of `s` contains the address of the first character of an array of `char`, sort of like the following<sup>1</sup>:

```
   +---+         +---+---+---+
s: |   | ------> |'1'|'2'| 0 |
   +---+         +---+---+---+
   |   | ----+
   +---+     |   +---+---+---+    
   |   | -+  +-> |'3'|'4'| 0 |
   +---+  |      +---+---+---+ 
    ...   |
          |      +---+---+---+
          +----> |'5'|'6'| 0 |
                 +---+---+---+
```

Thus, `s[0]` points to the *string* `"12"`, `s[1]` points to the string `"34"`, etc.  Each `s[i]` is passed to the `digitCounts` function, which walks through the string character by character and checks each to see if it is a digit.

The C language definition guarantees that the values of the digit *characters* `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, etc., are sequential, so any character value between `'0'` and `'9'` must be a digit character.  So the condition

```
if ( '0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9' )
```

is checking to see if each `s[i]` is a digit character (character constants like `'0'` and `'9'` are delimited by single quotes).  Note that there is a library function that does this same thing, with the bonus that it takes locale into account:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
if ( isdigit( s[i] ) ) // does the same thing as the line above.
```

Your professor's code is ... not awesome.  It would have been nice if he used different names for the array of strings in `main` (such as `numberStringList`) vs. the input parameter to `digitCounts` (such as `numberString`); I think that accounts for some of your confusion.  And he should have shown you how to use the `isdigit` function instead of hand-hacking the check.

---

1. In `main`, `s` is declared as an array of pointer to `char` (`char *[]`).  The size of the array is taken from the number of initializers in the initializer list.
   Each string literal in the initializer is also an array of `char`, but under most circumstances array expressions are converted ("decay") to pointer expressions, and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.  So each `s[i]` stores the *address* of the string literal, not the literal itself.

Comment: Is it ok to think of `char* s[] = {"12, 34, 5 ...` as a two-dimensional array? For the function `digitCounts`, how could I change the code to look at "12", as a whole, instead of, "1", then "2", separately? Like this? `while( s*[i] != '\0' )`?

Comment: @CheetahBongos: I wouldn't consider it a 2D array, since the array "rows" (the string literals themselves) aren't guaranteed to be adjacent in memory.  You can certainly index into it *as though* it were a 2D array (`s[0][0] == '1'`, `s[0][1] == '2'`, `s[1][0] == '3'`, etc.), but it's not laid out in memory like a 2D array.

Comment: @CheetahBongos: To take the string as a whole, just use `s` without any subscript.  However, you can't compare *strings* against individual characters - `s != '\0'` won't work, or at least it won't do what you want.  C string handling is *extremely* primitive - there's no string data type as such.  They're simply arrays of `char`, and most string processing in C is actually done character by character.

Comment: @CheetahBongos Rather than 2D, which can imply a rectangular matrix, the term for this type of array is "ragged array" or array of arrays.

Comment: @John Bode: Does c handling strings character by character make it slower than other languages at string processing?

Comment: @CheetahBongos: Most mainstream languages do string processing character by character under the hood, but they hide it behind higher-level language constructs.

Comment: @John Bode: thank you for taking the time to help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while( s[i] != '\0' ) //while char at index i is not '\0' (end of string)
{
    if('0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9') //if char at index i is between '0' and '9' (a digit)
    counts[ s[i] - '0' ]++; // increase digit count. (counts is an array of       size 10 where each index corresponds to digits 0-9

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while( s[i] != '\0' ){
   if('0' <= s[i] && s[i] <= '9')
      counts[ s[i] - '0' ]++;
   i++;
}
```

This loop iterates until `s[i]` is equal to `'\0'`. Then charcters are compared i.e `'0'<=s[i]` in this both are characters not string(compared on basis of ASCII values ).

Then if condition is fulfilled count at particular index is incremented in array `counts`. If charcter at `s[i]` is `'1'` then count of index is incresed by one. This `'s[i]-'0'` , gives the particular integer as `'1'-'0'` is `1` as difference between their ASCII values.

Answer (score 0):

Those are all `char`.

With that `if` statement you understand if the character is a number (the disequalities are actually working on the ASCII values of every `char`).

Answer (score 0):

Here `char* s[]` means **two dimensional array of characters or array of strings**. And in `digitCounts` the argument is `char* s` which is **one dimensional array or a string**. That's why, `s[0]` or the first element of s[] will be '1', not '12'.

Also, `'1' <= '9'` means ASCII value comparison of character 1 and 9.